# Calling function once

Tags: c++, winapi

```
    if (GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) & 0x80)
    {
        func();
    }
```

It calls func() like 4 times when I press key
I want it to call only once when I press key

EDIT:

```
    SHORT keyState;
    SHORT keyState2;
    SHORT keyState3;

    static bool toogle1 = false;
    static bool toogle2 = false;
    static bool toogle3 = false;

    if (keyState = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) && !toogle1)
    {
        toogle1 = true;
    }
    else
        toogle1 = !toogle1;

    if (keyState2 = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD0) && !toogle2)
    {
        toogle2 = true;
    }
    else
        toogle2 = !toogle2;

    if (keyState3 = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1) && !toogle3)
    {
        toogle3 = true;
    }
    else
        toogle3 = !toogle3;
```

Here is how I did it, will it work?

Comment: on first call raise a flag `handled = true` and erase it when `VK_UP`

Comment: give me pseudo code instead

Comment: See first comment for pseudocode.

Comment: How about you first start with the [tour] and read [ask]. That was actually a valuable hint what is wrong and your behaviour is inacceptable.

Comment: The posted code calls `func();` at most once. If the question is about some other code not shown, you'll need to post *that* complete code.

Comment: you are wrong, it calls multiple times when holding key

Comment: You have to adorn it with a loop for `func()` to be called multiple times.

Comment: @mynameisjef Again, the posted code has *one* line that calls `func();`, which is inside an `if` block. That line can be executed at most once. Whether that code is part of an enclosing loop, or is called from a message handler that gets invoked multiple times, nobody can guess since you did not show any other code. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Whenever control reaches this piece of code and `if (GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) & 0x80)` is `true` the function `func();` is called exactly _once_. If the code is called in each frame, probably multiple times a second, that's a whole other problem. Basically Alex  Larionov told you what to do in the very first comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
static bool once = false;
if (GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) & 0x80)
{
    if (!once)
     {    once = true; func();     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you run this in a loop. Your idea with toggling a flag when called is not bad, but since you toggle it back in the else case, you call `func()` half as often as before (every 2nd time).
When you want to call it again (I think you want, according to your code), when the key is pressed again, but not spam the function call, you can use a variable to store which key was pressed last and only call `func()`, when it was another key (you can also add a "no key pressed" state.

If you really just want to call it once, just remove your else statements.